# Java ProcessBuilder and bash

Tags: java, bash, processbuilder

I am trying to execute a bash script from Java with `ProcessBuilder`
my code is :

```
 Process createUser = buildProcess(
            "/bin/su",
            "-c",
            "\"/opt/somedir/testdir/current/bin/psql",
            "--command",
            commandForUserCreation,
            /* "'select * from users'", */
            "--dbname",
            "mydbname\"",
            "myuser"
            );
```

The problem is that I receive error:

```
 /bin/su: unrecognized option '--dbname'
```

If I put `echo` in first place of my commands it prints correct command in bash and if I copy/paste this command it works!

Please, help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to supply the whole command to execute by `su` as a single argument. Try this:

```
 Process createUser = buildProcess(
            "/bin/su",
            "-c",
            "/opt/vmware/vpostgres/current/bin/psql --command " + commandForUserCreation + " --dbname mydbname",
            myuser
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use in processBuilder:

```
String[] command = new String[] {"echo", "Hello"};
String workspace = "/bin/su";
System.out.println("Trying to run command: "+ Arrays.toString(command));
ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
probuilder.directory(new File(workspace));

Process process = probuilder.start();
InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String line;
System.out.printf("Output of running %s is:\n",Arrays.toString(command));
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

I hope it helps.